# Compute Intra class correlation coefficient in python using statsmodels

Tags: python, linear-regression, bioinformatics, statsmodels, mixed-models

I'm using statsmodels.formula.api.mixedlm to calculate intra-class correlation coefficient and other metrics.

My dataset is really simple it contains a feature_value, a visit date, and a subject id.

I'm using the following block of code to fit the mixed linear model

```
mdf = smf.mixedlm("feature_value ~ 1+ visit", data,
    groups=data["subject_id"]
           )
mdf = mdf.fit()
```

The ICC is defined as : between_subject_variance / (between_subject_variance + within_subject_variance)

I know how to extract those metrics with SAS (with the Var_bw and Var_wt parameters), but
I have no clue how to access those with the python model, especially the within-subject variance  (I tried mdf.cov_re / (mdf.cov_re + mdf.scale) but I'm not convinced by the results). Any suggestions? I don't really care about the ICC what I really want is the between and within-subject variance.

Answer (score 0):

The `cov_re` attribute from the fit returns the covariance matrix of the random effects, which includes the between-subject variance. The square root of `scale` parameter gives you the within-subject variance

```
mdf_fit = mdf.fit()

between_var = mdf_fit.cov_re.diagonal().sum()

within_var = mdf_fit.scale ** 2
```